# Android http post with special character (utf-8?)

Tags: android, http, special-characters

my php-site is echoing "här är du/x vår i sikte" which is shown as "här är du/x vår i sikte" in my chrome browser. 
But when I read it with httppost in my java/android app all the special characters (åäö) is shown as a questionmark. My webhosting service uses UtF-8. Is there a way to convert my string?
Here is my code:

```
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
try {
    // Create a new HTTP Client
    DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Setup the get request
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("my.php");
    try {
        post.setHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder
                .create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        final HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        post.setEntity((HttpEntity) entity);

        //builder.addTextBody("rubrik_nr", all_rubrik, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);     
        HttpResponse resp = defaultClient.execute(post);
    }catch(Exception E){

    }
    // Execute the request in the client
    HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient
            .execute(post);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
Log.d("DEBUG", "response: " + response.toString());


} catch (IOException e) {
Log.d("DEBUG", "j " + response.toString());
e.printStackTrace();
}

return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using google ? it's a very good source before asking people to write code for you , SO is helpful when you're stuck . Greetings.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing. I havent been asking any questions before learning coding, but now I feel stuck. that's why I am asking here. I have been searching/googeled it for some days now, but can't find a basic code that works for me.. even copy/paste hasn't been working.. But I get your point me asking for a code. An usefull link that I have't found would also be great :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give you a sample code but it would be useful if you could write exactly where you have problems and what you don't understand.
You will need an AsyncTask for the network operation. Try out the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new AsyncConnection().execute();

    }

    // This is the code for async task.
    public class AsyncConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // you can use your result string here
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                // Create a new HTTP Client
                DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // Setup the get request
                HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("URL");

                // Execute the request in the client
                HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient
                        .execute(httpGetRequest);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
                String inputLine;

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                Log.d("DEBUG", "response: " + response.toString());


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "j " + response.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response.toString();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx, that kind of made it.

Comment: I now have some problems with httppost, but hopefully I'll find the answer somewhere where I haven't found them yet. I might comeback here with som question regarding your code, but for now that's good. Thanks anyway for you answer. I hope I will figure out "android/java" some day :)